# How to generate random patterns using LFSR and i am using different partial seed value

Tags: verilog

As I said, seedValue wire is holding a 10 bit partial seed which I want to assign to a register when the rst signal is 1 it enters the block and the last statement of this block assigns the seedValue wire to the register temp so that when the if condition if((temp!=10'b0000000000) || (temp!=10'bxxxxxxxxxx)) is executed it enters the block and then the seedValue is concatenated with 12'b000000000000 and then I get my 32-bit seed value through which I am expecting to have random patterns from the LFSR after that the register temp is assigned zero values so that the else block must execute from which I am expection to get random patterns, but the following code is not working. I am new to Verilog and FPGA world, somebody please help me. The following code is written in Verilog.

```
module TestPatternGenerator(input wire clk, input wire rst, input wire enable, 
input wire sel, input wire[9:0] seedValue, output reg[127:0] valueO);

integer i;
reg [31:0] patternGenerate[0:3],tempOne;    
reg [9:0] temp;


always @(posedge clk)begin

    if((sel == 1)&&(enable==1))begin 

        if(rst)begin
            valueO = 128'b0;
            patternGenerate[0]<=32'b0;
            patternGenerate[1]<=32'b0;
            patternGenerate[2]<=32'b0;
            patternGenerate[3]<=32'b0;
            tempOne <= 32'b11111111111111111111111111111111;
            temp <= seedValue;
        end

        else if((temp!=10'b0000000000) || (temp!=10'bxxxxxxxxxx))begin
                tempOne <= {12'b000000000000,seedValue};
                $display("%h",tempOne);
                temp <= 10'b0000000000;
        end 

        else begin
            for(i=0;i<4;i=i+1)begin
                tempOne = {(tempOne[31] ^ tempOne[25] ^ tempOne[22] ^ tempOne[21] ^ tempOne[15] ^ tempOne[11] ^ tempOne[10] ^ tempOne[9] ^ tempOne[7] ^ tempOne[6] ^ tempOne[4] ^ tempOne[3] ^ tempOne[1] ^ tempOne[0]), tempOne[31:1]};
                patternGenerate[i] = tempOne;
            end
            valueO = {patternGenerate[3],patternGenerate[2],patternGenerate[1],patternGenerate[0]};

        end

    end
    i=i+1;
end
endmodule
```

code for testbench is given below

```
`timescale 10ns/1ns
module test_controller();

integer j;
reg [127:0] key_byte,valueI,oraI;
wire [127:0] state_byte;
wire [9:0] seedValue;
wire [47:0] result;
reg [7:0] iterate;
reg clk,rst,bistForDeternimistic,deterministicEnable,ecryptionEnable,enable,decryptionEnable,decryptionSecondEnable,bistMode,bistForEncryption,bistForDecryption,oraEnable;


wire [127:0] state_out_dec,state_out_enc,state_second_dec;
wire [31:0] state_out_ora;
reg [31:0] signatureToMatch;
wire load,ready;


TestPatternGenerator tpg (clk,rst,enable,bistMode,seedValue,state_byte);


always #3 clk = ~clk;

initial begin
    bistMode <= 1;
    key_byte <= 128'h5468617473206D79204B756E67204675;
    bistForDecryption <= 0;
    clk<=0;
    rst<=1;
    #5 rst<=0;
    iterate<=0;
    j<=0;
    bistForDeternimistic<=1;
    enable<=1;
end

always@(negedge clk)begin : deterministic_block
        if(j==100)begin
            disable deterministic_block;
        end

        if((bistMode==1) && (bistForDeternimistic==1))begin

            @(state_byte)begin
                $display("%h   %d",state_byte,$time);
            end
        end

        j=j+1;
end
endmodule
```

output i am getting only the first test pattern but it should generate 100 test patterns. So except the first test pattern, i am not getting the rest 99 patterns.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code, I don't see any patterns (the `$display` statements are not executed).  This is because the `enable` signal is unknown when `rst` is 1.

If I delay the `rst` rising edge to occur after `enable` is set to 1, I see 100 patterns:

```
initial begin
    bistMode <= 1;
    key_byte <= 128'h5468617473206D79204B756E67204675;
    bistForDecryption <= 0;
    clk<=0;
    rst<=1;
    iterate<=0;
    j<=0;
    bistForDeternimistic<=1;
    enable<=1;
    #5 rst<=0;
end
```

This is a partial output:

```
00000000000000000000000000000000                      3
afffffff5fffffffbfffffff7fffffff                      9
2affffff55ffffffabffffff57ffffff                     15
72afffffe55fffffcabfffff957fffff                     21
272affff4e55ffff9cabffff3957ffff                     27
4272afff84e55fff09cabfff13957fff                     33
```

---

You mention the `seedValue` signal in your question, but it is undriven  (the value `z`).  You declared the signal as a `wire`, and wires default to `z` when they are not assigned.

To drive it with a know value for the full duration of the simulation, you could use, for example:

```
wire [9:0] seedValue = 1;
```

If you want to drive it like your other inputs, you should declare is as a `reg`.